# Что означает фраза про lvalue в абзаце 1 раздела 6.3.2.1 черновика стандарта C2x n2596?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

В черновике стандарта есть фраза:

> if an lvalue does not designate an object when it is evaluated, the behavior is undefined.

Какой объект может быть not evaluated, чтобы он мог в то же время являться locator value (lvalue)? Перечислите, пожалуйста , такие объекты.

[c2x draft standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2596.pdf)

Comment: Может быть что-то такое `*(double *)malloc(8) = 3.14;` подходит?

Comment: То есть, левым операндом должно быть не вычисленное выражение, которое нельзя вычислить и на которое берётся указатель?

Comment: Долго думал, но так и не понял ваш вопрос, особенно *`"... которое нельзя вычислить и на которое берётся указатель"`*.   / Я предполагаю, что если в процессе спекулятивных вычислений (это когда CPU параллельно выполняет инструкции по нескольким *возможным* путям) мы можем получить как valid, так и недопустимое значение указателя, то стандарт разрешает UB.  (мне тоже было бы интересно послушать толковое объяснение стандарта (с примерами кода) от кого-нибудь из его разработчиков)

Comment: Фраза «when it is evaluated» относится не к объекту, а к lvalue-expression. При вычислении lvalue-выражения, если это выражение фактически не ссылается, не обозначает живой объект, то поведение не определено. Например здесь: `int* p = NULL; *p = 1;`выражение `*p` не обозначает объект, следовательно UB. Или здесь: `int x; (&x)[1] = 5;` выражение `(&x)[1]` также не ссылается на объект, следовательно UB. А пример с `malloc` UB не является (при условии, что `malloc` вернёт ненулевой указатель, и `sizeof(double)` не больше восьми).

Comment: Операнд `sizeof` (ну кроме VLA), например, не вычисляется, так что `sizeof(*(int*)0)` это ОК.